# On a solution to a triple integral.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I want to calculate the function $f(x,y,z) = z$ on the set $B = \{ (x,y,z) \in R^3 | z \ge \sqrt{7x^2 + 3y^2}, 2x + z \le 3 \}$

I tried to solve it without cylindrical substitutions.

the solution is $$\int_0^{\sqrt{7}} \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_{\sqrt{28 - 28r \cos \theta + 3 r^2 \cos^2 \theta + 4r^2}}^{7-2r \cos \theta} r t dt d \theta d r$$

So this is solved by setting $x = r \cos \theta - 2, y = r \sin \theta , z =t$

But I don’t understand how this substitution helps us, and how is $r$ between $0$ and $\sqrt{7}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Theorem A:** Let $b\ge a$. $$\begin{align}
> &(t-a)(t-b)\le 0\iff a\le t\le b\\
> &(t-a)(t-b)\ge0\iff t\le a \text{ or } t\ge b 
> \end{align}$$

Proof:
$$\begin{align}
&a\le t\le b\implies t-a\ge0, t-b\le 0\implies (t-a)(t-b)\le0\\
&t\le a\le b\implies t-a\le0, t-b\le 0\implies (t-a)(t-b)\ge0\\
&t\ge b\ge a\implies t-a\ge0, t-b\ge 0\implies (t-a)(t-b)\ge0
\end{align}$$

> Limits in Cartesian coordinates (order of integration: $\mathrm{\iiint_Vz\, dz\, dy\, dx}$)

At the very beginning our integral looks like
$$\mathrm{
\iiint_Vg(x,y,z)\,dz\,dy\,dx 
}$$
As we're integrating with respect to $z$ first we'll fix $x,y$ and consequently, the upper and lower limits of $z$ will be functions $x,y$. After we're done integrating with respect to $ z$ first we'll be left with an integral that looks like
$$\mathrm{
\iint_Vh(x,y)\,dy\,dx
}$$
Now we have to integrate wrt $y$ first and therefore we fix $x$ to find the limits of $y$ i.e. the limits of $y$ will be functions of $x$. After we're done intgrating with respect to $y$ we'll be left with an integral that looks like the familiar single-variable definite integral
$$\mathrm{
\int_a^b F(x)\,dx
}$$
where $a,b$ are constants. So our integral looks like
$$\mathrm{
\int_a^b\int_{p(x)}^{q(x)}\int_{m(x,y)}^{n(x,y)}g(x,y,z)\,dz\,dy\,dx
}$$
The two inequalities in the definition of $B$ immediately yields the limits for $z$ as
$$\color{blue}{\sqrt{7x^2+3y^2}\le z\le3-2x}$$
As the lower limit is positive, so is upper-limit and therefore we have
$$
7x^2+3y^2\le(3-2x)^2
$$
which after a bit of algebra reduces to
$$\begin{align}
\implies & 0\le y^2\le3-4x-x^2\color{red}{\cdots(1)}\\
\implies &(y-\sqrt{3-4x-x^2})(y+\sqrt{3-4x-x^2})\le0\\
\implies&\color{blue}{-\sqrt{3-4x-x^2}\le y\le\sqrt{3-4x-x^2}}\quad\text{[ by theorem A ]}
\end{align}$$
which gives the limits for $y$ and lastly from $(1)$ we have
$$\begin{align}
&0\le 3-4x-x^2\\
\implies& 0\le 7-(x+2)^2\\
\implies& (x+2-\sqrt 7)(x+2+\sqrt 7)\le0\\
\implies& \color{blue}{-2-\sqrt 7\le x\le-2+\sqrt7}\quad\text{[ by theorem A ]}
\end{align}$$
which are the required limits for $x$. So our integral becomes
$$\mathrm{
\int_{-2-\sqrt 7}^{-2+\sqrt 7}\int_{-\sqrt{3-4x-x^2}}^{\sqrt{3-4x-x^2}}\int_{\sqrt{7x^2+3y^2}}^{3-2x}z\,dz\,dy\,dx
}={147\pi\over4}$$

> Limits in Cartesian coordinates (order of integration: $\mathrm{\iiint_Vz\, dy\, dz\, dx}$)

From the discussion in the previous section we understand our integral in this case should look like
$$\mathrm{
\int_A^B\int_{P(x)}^{Q(x)}\int_{M(x,z)}^{N(x,z)}g(x,y,z)\,dy\,dz\,dx
}$$
We manipulate the first inequality defining $B$ as follows
$$
y^2\le{z^2-7x^2\over 3}\implies \left(y-\sqrt{z^2-7x^2\over3}\right)\left(y+\sqrt{z^2-7x^2\over3}\right)\le0\\
\therefore \color{blue}{-\sqrt{z^2-7x^2\over3}\le y\le\sqrt{z^2-7x^2\over3}}\quad \text{[ by theorem A ]}
$$
$y$ has real limits iff
$$
7x^2\le z^2\iff -z\le\sqrt 7x\le z\cdots(2)
$$
The first inequality defining $B$ says $z\ge0$ and the $2$nd one says $z+2x\le3$. These two along with $(2)$ give us $4$ inequalities
$$\begin{align}
-&z\le\sqrt7 x\\
&z\ge\sqrt7 x\\
&z+2x\le3\\
&z\ge0
\end{align}$$ 
The region that satisfies all these inequalities is the union of grey and yellow areas in the figure below.

[image]

To get the limits for $z$ we fix $x$ which gives us a vertical line along which $z$ varies.

Grey area: $\color{blue}{-{\sqrt 7}x\le z\le3-2x,\;-2-\sqrt7\le x\le0}$

Yellow area: $\color{blue}{{\sqrt 7}x\le z\le3-2x,\;0\le x\le-2+\sqrt7}$

So our integral becomes
$$\mathrm{
\underbrace{\int_{-2-\sqrt7}^{0}\int_{-\sqrt7 x}^{3-2x}\int_{-\sqrt{{z^2-7x^2\over3}}}^{\sqrt{{z^2-7x^2\over3}}}z\,dy\,dz\,dx}_{\text{grey}}+\underbrace{\int^{-2+\sqrt7}_{0}\int_{\sqrt7 x}^{3-2x}\int_{-\sqrt{{z^2-7x^2\over3}}}^{\sqrt{{z^2-7x^2\over3}}}z\,dy\,dz\,dx}_{\text{yellow}}
}={147\pi\over4}$$

> Limits in cylindrical polar coordinates (order of integration: $\mathrm{\iiint_Vz\,r\,dz\,d\theta\,dr}$)

$$\begin{align}
&\sqrt{7(r\cos\theta-2)^2+3r^2\sin^2\theta}\le z\le3-2(r\cos\theta-2)\\
\implies&\color{blue}{\sqrt{28-28r\cos\theta+4r^2\cos^2\theta+3r^2}\le z\le7-2r\cos\theta}\\
&\color{blue}{0\le\theta\le2\pi}\\
&r^2={(x+2)^2+y^2}={y^2-(3-4x-x^2)+7}\le0+7=7\;\;\text{[ using (1) ]}\\
\implies& \color{blue}{0\le r\le\sqrt7}
\end{align}$$

> Calculation of the integral

Indeed the polar substitution makes the evaluation of the integral easier here
$$\mathrm{
\int_0^{\sqrt 7}\int_0^{2\pi}\int^{7-2\cos\theta}_\sqrt{28-28r\cos\theta+4r^2\cos^2\theta+3r^2}zr\,dz\,d\theta\,dr\\
=\int_0^{\sqrt 7}\int_0^{2\pi}r{z^2\over2}\Big{|}^{7-2\cos\theta}_\sqrt{28-28r\cos\theta+4r^2\cos^2\theta+3r^2}\,d\theta\,dr\\
=\int_0^{\sqrt 7}\int_0^{2\pi}r{(21-3r^2)\over2}\,d\theta\,dr\\
=\int_0^{\sqrt 7}\pi r(21-3r^2)\,dr\\
={147\pi\over4}
}$$

Comment: Thank you a lot Jack but you think to highly of my understanding abilities. If you could put an explanation between each step I will give you 100 reputation since you have helped me many times and I am particularly interested in understanding how to do these integrals.

Comment: Also is there only one way to find the limits in integration in Cartesian coordinates? say I started with $x$ instead, how would one proceed? I am asking so I can get a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: @Monolite Never mind I'll edit this answer.

Comment: Thank you again Jack, just a quick question right off the bat: how did you get $0 \le \theta \le 2 \pi$  from $\sqrt{28-28r\cos\theta+4r^2\cos^2\theta+3r^2}\le z\le7-2r\cos\theta$?  Because $-7 \le - 2r \cos \theta$ and this is true for all $\theta$?

Comment: ${7\over2r}\ge{7\over2\sqrt{7}}>1$. Your inequality is $\cos\theta\le {7\over2r}$ as cosine is bounded by $1$ and RHS is greater than $1$, the inequality is satisfied for all $\theta$.

Comment: An other thing: why do the solutions make that substitution instead of $x = (1/ \sqrt{7} ) r \cos \theta$ and $y =  (1/ \sqrt{3} ) r \sin \theta$ ? isn't it simpler with this more obvious substitution?

Comment: How do I reward your answer? I thought an option would appear after 24h.

Comment: Oh ok 13 hours until I can give a bounty when I uncheck your answer.